# Executing commands on a remote server via winrm failed

Tags: powershell, winrm

I am trying to remotely manage a windows server which is Azure AD Domain joined. I have activated winrm on both machines. My user has administrator rights and I am working from an elevated prompt. I have even set the Server as trusted host just in case. No matter what I try I keep getting this error message.

> Connecting to remote server xxx failed with the following error message: The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the authentication schme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. You can get more information about that by running the following command: winrm help config. For more information, see the about_remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>
> - CategoryInfo: OpenError: (xxx) [], PSRemotingTranportException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId: ServerNotTrusted,PSSessionStateBroken

I am connected via VPN to the company network, I can also ping the server. I also successfully opened a telnet to the server on the port winrm uses normally.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does DCOM remoting work? WMI.

Comment: How can I test this?

Comment: A simple `Get-Wmiobject -ComputerName compname -Class win32_bios`

Comment: Yes this does work, or at least I get a response and not an error message..